# Bind a method which returns DataTable to GridView using JQuery

Tags: jquery, gridview, datatable

**example :**

```
public DataTable GetCountries()  
{  
//all sql connection  
//fetching data into a datatable


return objDataTable // returns a datatable  
}


public void BindGridView()  
{  
GridView1.DataSource = GetCountries();  
GridView1.DataBind();  
}
```

The thing which i can achieve in above code is Binding a GridView,
but i want to Bind GridView1 using JQuery and the DataTable returned by GetCountries() method...

Please can anyone give a simplest example to me...?

Answer (score 0):

You can also used jtable. It is more flexibly integrated. Please see this link:

[UsingWithAspNetWebFormsPageMethods](http://jtable.org/Tutorials/UsingWithAspNetWebFormsPageMethods)

Or you can also download source code from codeproject:

[Resizable-asp-net-Gridview-columns-using-Jquery](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/366013/Resizable-asp-net-Gridview-columns-using-Jquery)

Answer (score 0):

ASPX PAGE (Default.aspx)

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title>Asp.net Bind Data to Datatable using JQuery or JSON</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
url: "Default.aspx/BindDatatable",
data: "{}",
dataType: "json",
success: function(data) {
for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
$("#gvDetails").append("<tr><td>" + data.d[i].UserId + "</td><td>" + data.d[i].UserName + "</td><td>" + data.d[i].Location + "</td></tr>");
}
},
error: function(result) {
alert("Error");
}
});
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
table,th,td
{
border:1px solid black;
border-collapse:collapse;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:GridView ID="gvDetails" runat="server">
<HeaderStyle BackColor="#DC5807" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="White" />
</asp:GridView>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

.CS FILE (Default.aspx.cs)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.Services;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (!IsPostBack)
{
BindColumnToGridview();
}
}
/// <summary>
/// This method is used to bind dummy row to gridview to bind data using JQuery
/// </summary>
private void BindColumnToGridview()
{
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("UserId");
dt.Columns.Add("UserName");
dt.Columns.Add("Location");
dt.Rows.Add();
gvDetails.DataSource = dt;
gvDetails.DataBind();
gvDetails.Rows[0].Visible = false;
}

[WebMethod]
public static UserDetails[] BindDatatable()
{
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
List<UserDetails> details = new List<UserDetails>();

using (SqlConnection con=new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=true"))
{
using (SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand("select TOP 10 UserId,UserName,Location from UserInformation",con))
{
con.Open();
SqlDataAdapter da= new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
da.Fill(dt);
foreach (DataRow dtrow in dt.Rows)
{
UserDetails user=new UserDetails();
user.UserId = dtrow["UserId"].ToString();
user.UserName = dtrow["UserName"].ToString();
user.Location = dtrow["Location"].ToString();
details.Add(user);
}
}
}
return details.ToArray();
}
public class UserDetails
{
public string UserId { get; set; }
public string UserName { get; set; }
public string Location { get; set; }
}
}
```